# why do i not have 'gamecenter' option in my list of capabilities

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, game-center

It seems the "gamecenter" option on my list of  available capabilities for my application is not available for me. I have selected and signed in to my team which has an appropriate apple ID. Is there a particular reason why that option is not available for me?

[image]

Comment: Maybe [this Apple article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/adding-capabilities-to-your-app) can be of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/adding-capabilities-to-your-app
Some capabilities such as 'gamecenter' requires extra configurations first to your app such as paying the yearly fee to be on apple developer program before being allowed to access them.